# Conversão de texto para número em C# para gravar em DB

Tags: c#, mysql

Estou usando essa conversão para pegar a string do `txtvalor.text` e transformá-la em um valor assim: `1.500,80`

```
curso.Valor = double.Parse(txtValor.Text);
```

Exemplo eu digito 1.500,80. E gostaria que gravasse no banco assim também, no banco de dados MySQL.

Comment: Assim como? Com o ponto e a virgula?

Comment: Qual a string de exemplo que está em txtValor.Text ?

Comment: 1º obrigado por me responder. Eu gostaria de de passar um valor em moeda para o banco. tipo 1.440.30. Já tentei double, decimal e float, mas nenhum deles grava as virgulas ou os pontos.

Comment: Mas tu tentou esses tipos no banco ou no code behind lá? Poste a estrutura da sua tabela (aa que você tentou);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Evite usar campos texto no BD para guardar valores numéricos. Além de ser uma péssima prática (exceto se existir um forte objetivo para isto) aumenta o tamanho do banco de dados e dificulta, em muito, as pesquisas. Também ocasiona queda de performance.
Para gravar o valor informado na sua pergunta (1.500,80), após fazer a conversão no C# para DOUBLE (eu aconselho que você utilize DECIMAL ao invés de DOUBLE), grave o valor em um campo do tipo NUMERIC no MySQL.

Comment: Boa recomendação. Mas hoje tenho visto muito o pessoal usar campos numéricos para gravar textos. Por exemplo, telefone, CEP, CPF, códigos numéricos. Estes campos são textos que apenas aceitam dígitos numéricos mas não são campos numéricos. Não são usados para fazer contas. mas a melhor recomendação é usar `decimal`no lugar de `double`. Me impressiona como ainda tenha programador que usa `double` para valores monetários.

Comment: Bem lembrado @bigown. Campos do tipo telefone, CPF e CNPJ por exemplo, necessitam realmente de um campo do tipo texto, apesar do valor armazenado ser numérico. Um dos argumentos para isto é que estes valores podem ser precedido de 0 (zero), o que causaria inconsistência caso fosse gravado em campo do tipo numérico.

Answer (score 0):

Formatação faz parte de um aspecto de visualização (View), ou seja, a forma mais reutilizável seria gravar no banco de dados o valor numérico  correspondente e formatar da melhor maneira em cada um dos fronts da aplicação.

Mas se você realmente quer forçar a gravação, mude o tipo do campo no BD para varchar (ou outro tipo textual), formate na aplicação e depois grave. Quando você recuperar o valor ele já vira formatado.

Comment: -1 por utilizar VARCHAR ou campo texto para guardar valor numerico no BD.

Comment: E. Thomas, eu não RECOMENDEI o uso de campo texto para valores no BD. O meu primeiro parágrafo sugere justamente o contrário. O segundo parágrafo é uma forma de viabilizar a gravação que ele deseja, mesmo sendo um padrão ruim de ser seguido. Não sabemos todos os requisitos e escopo, apenas opinamos para ajudar.